# Visual Basic For Applications " subscript out of range" error

Tags: excel, vba, scripting

"  I am getting a subscript out of range error after adding two new elements to an array. I remove the elements and re-run the code and it works. I need to know where to change the range so that it accommodates the array elements.  This is the edited code: products = Array("BALANCER", "SKIN LIGHTENER", "FIRM AND FADE 6%", "FIRM AND FADE 8%")
After adding the two additional elements the error is thrown.
Research is showing that the array is the issue however after making adjustments the error message is still being thrown. "

"Here is the original code:"

```
    Public Sub Dermesse_Dashboard(SD As Date, ED As Date)

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.RecordSet
    Dim com As ADODB.Command
    Dim ConnectionString As String, StoredProcName As String
    Dim StartDate As ADODB.Parameter, EndDate As ADODB.Parameter, Product As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim excelrange As String
    Dim DateRange As String
    Dim RCount As Integer
    Dim products As Variant
    products = Array("BALANCER", "SKIN LIGHTENER")
    
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.RecordSet
    Set com = New ADODB.Command
    
    Workbooks.Open ("\\apfssvr01\Arrow_RX\Reports\Templates\Dermesse_Dashboard(Template).xlsx")
        
    ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=ARWSQL01;initial catalog=futurefill;User Id=endicia;Pwd=endicia;trusted_connection=yes;"
    
    On Error GoTo CloseConnection
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    cn.Open ConnectionString
    cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient

    StoredProcName = "Dermesse_Shipped_by_Product"

    With com
        .ActiveConnection = cn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = StoredProcName
    End With
    
    Set StartDate = com.CreateParameter("@StartDate", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, , SD)
    com.Parameters.Append StartDate

    Set EndDate = com.CreateParameter("@Enddate", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, , ED)
    com.Parameters.Append EndDate
        
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Select
    

    'loop through each item in products.
    For Each i In products
        'remove the product parameter if it exists so we can set it to the next product
        If Product Is Nothing = False Then
            com.Parameters.Delete (2)
        End If
        
        Set Product = com.CreateParameter("@Product", adVarChar, adParamInput, 200, i)
        com.Parameters.Append Product
    
        Set rs = com.Execute
        
        'add rows to the excel table if the record set if 2 or greater.
        'if we dont any tables below the first could be over written
        If rs.RecordCount >= 2 Then
            For j = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 3
                ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Ship " & i).ListRows.Add (2)
            Next
        End If
        
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Ship " & i).DataBodyRange.Select
        Selection.CopyFromRecordset rs

        rs.Close
    Next
    
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(6).Select
    
        StoredProcName = "Dermesse_Shipped_wOrder"
        
        With com
            .ActiveConnection = cn
            .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
            .CommandText = StoredProcName
        End With
        
        If Product Is Nothing = False Then
            com.Parameters.Delete (2)
        End If
        
        Set Product = com.CreateParameter("@Product", adVarChar, adParamInput, 200, "Dermesse")
        com.Parameters.Append Product
    
        Set rs = com.Execute
        RCount = rs.RecordCount
        
        With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Invoice DERMESSE")
            If rs.RecordCount >= 2 Then
                For j = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 3
                    .ListRows.Add (2)
                Next
            End If
            
            .DataBodyRange.Select
            
            Selection.CopyFromRecordset rs
            
            .ListColumns(12).Range.Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
        End With
        
        rs.Close
  
    cn.Close
        'set a data fee value for each record.  look at the order number of a specific line.  if the line above or below are the same
        'the data fee is 7.5 else is 10
        r = 9
        For i = 0 To RCount - 1
            If ActiveSheet.Range("C" & r + i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & (r + i) - 1).Value Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(r + i, 12).Value = 7.5
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("C" & r + i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & (r + i) + 1).Value Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(r + i, 12).Value = 7.5
            Else
                ActiveSheet.Cells(r + i, 12).Value = 10
            End If
        Next i
    
    If SD <> ED Then
        DateRange = Format(SD, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " through " & Format(ED, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    Else
        DateRange = Format(SD, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    End If
    
    With ActiveWorkbook
        For i = 1 To .Sheets.Count
            .Sheets(i).Select
            .Sheets(i).Range("A2").Value = DateRange
        Next
        .Sheets("Dermesse Dashboard").Select
    End With
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("\\apfssvr01\Arrow_RX\Reports\Dermesse\DERMESSE_Dashboard(" & DateRange & ").xlsx"), FileFormat:=51
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    frmSwitchboard.lblDD.Caption = "Report Complete"
    Exit Sub
    
CloseConnection:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    frmSwitchboard.lblDD.Caption = "Error: " & Error
    cn.Close
    If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please note what specific line throws the subscript out of range.

Comment: Also please note that `For Each i In products` is a doubly confusing way to loop over an array. Normal would be `Dim i As Long`, `For i = LBound(products) to Ubound(products)`, then use `products(i)` to refer to the array element.

Comment: Also `If Product Is Nothing = False` wants to be `If Not Product Is Nothing`, and `RCount As Integer` will explode at row 32,768.

Comment: @BigBen unfortunately my debugger did not show the specific line that is thrwoing the error. however with doing some sluething the script runs fine with this line of code 
```
 products = Array("BALANCER", "SKIN LIGHTENER")
```
but as soon as the extra elements are added using the following code
```
products = Array("BALANCER", "SKIN LIGHTENER", "FIRM AND FADE 6%", "FIRM AND FADE 8%")
```
it fails... The change in the array size is the culprit, now to fix it.....that is the question

Comment: Do you have tables named correctly for the new items i.e. prefixed with the word `"Ship " ` ? Try adding one item at a time till it fails.

Comment: Adding one item to the products array fails as well.